# What is the difference between "be_true" and "be true" in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

Can any one please explain me about the difference between `be_true` and `be true` in Ruby with simple example.  I have also seen `be_true` and `be_false` are changed to `be_truthy` and `be_falsey`

I have an example where `'be true'` worked, but when I tried to use `'be_true'` or `'be_truthy'` spec failed.

I am using RSpec version 3.1.7

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283) `be_true` and `be_false` are now known as `be_truthy` and `be_falsy`.

The basic difference between `be true` and `be_truthy` or `be false` and `be_falsy` is that `be_falsy`/`be_truthy` matcher passes if the "expected result"(i.e. any object) ***is***(for *`be_falsy`*)/ ***is not***(for *`be_truthy`*) `nil` or `false`, while on the other hand `be true` and `be false` use `==` for validating your "expected result"(*boolean object*) to be equal to `true`/ `false`.

What it means from [rspec expectations' truthiness](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#truthiness) is:

```
expect(actual).to be_truthy   # passes if actual is truthy (not nil or false)
expect(actual).to be true     # passes if actual == true
expect(actual).to be_falsy    # passes if actual is falsy (nil or false)
expect(actual).to be false    # passes if actual == false
expect(actual).to be_nil      # passes if actual is nil
expect(actual).to_not be_nil  # passes if actual is not nil
```

#### **Examples -**

For `be true` and `be false`:

```
it { expect(true).to be true }        # passes
it { expect("string").to be true }    # fails
it { expect(nil).to be true }         # fails
it { expect(false).to be true }       # fails

it { expect(false).to be false }      # passes
it { expect("string").to be false}    # fails
it { expect(nil).to be false}         # fails
it { expect(true).to be false}        # fails
```

For `be_truthy` and `be_falsy`:

```
it { expect(true).to be_truthy }      # passes
it { expect("string").to be_truthy }  # passes
it { expect(nil).to be_truthy }       # fails
it { expect(false).to be_truthy }     # fails

it { expect(false).to be_falsy }      # passes
it { expect(nil).to be_falsy }        # passes
it { expect("string").to be_falsy}    # fails
it { expect(true).to be_falsy }       # fails
```

You can use any other object as "expected result" at the place of `"string"` except `nil`/`true`/`false`, because they are already present in the examples shown above.

Comment: when you say (be_truthy is true when not nil or false) you're kind of suggesting the wrong thing. Although your answer is correct and most of us get the idea, it's logically incorrect to say that, and should be modified to (be_truthy is true when not nil nor false). Or (be_truthy is true when not (nil or false)).

Comment: @moeabdol : I didn't understand your point. Could you point out where I said "be_truthy is true when not nil or false"? I would very much like to clarify if there's a misinterpretation that might have happened in the answer. :)

Comment: second paragraph, end of second line.

Comment: @moeabdol : this one: "while on the other hand be true and be false use == for validating your "expected result" to be equal to true/false."?

Comment: "be_falsy/be_truthy checks if the "expected result" is(for falsy)/is not(for truthy) nil or false"

Comment: @moeabdol : I see, the statement I made tries to say is: `be_truthy` passes if "expected result" is any object other than `nil` or `false`. It's just that I've put it that way. Will edit it later.